# Embedding Youtube playlist but starting from random video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've done plenty of searching but can't find a olsution so far...

I have a Youtube playlist. I want to embed it on a website. But instead of always starting at the first video, I want it to start at either a random video, or a at least a specific video (which I can randomly select with server side code).

I have looked at the options for the iframe embed URL and can't see a parameter that allows me any control over this. Is it possible to do?

Otherwise I presume I would need to do something in JavaScript with the API. Can someone paste or point me to some example code that I could use to accomplish this as I haven't used the Youtube API before?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generate a random number on your server and then use the index parameter in the url.  Here's an example where the playlist will start on the 7th item by adding index=7.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL9C5815B418D1508E&index=7" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The other option is to use the js api, and call loadPlaylist and include the index argument.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#loadPlaylist

**Edit: Since Google introduced YouTube's 3.0 API, the `index` parameter is now zero-based. Therefore, if we wanted to start at the 7th video, we'd modify the example above using `&index=6` instead of `&index=7`.

(Link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Queueing_Functions_for_Playlists)

Comment: Thanks for that, the index parameter will do the job. Although I guess I can't get a count of the number of videos (without using the API) I see that if I use an index greater than the actual number of videos it shows the first one anyway, which is fine.

Comment: sadly, the `index` thing is never mentioned in the API docs, even while they do a good job to keep track of changes over the years https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters nor could i find any such feature to choose a specific video from the playlist. :(

the only alternative i could find there would be using `playlist` parameters and manually building a comma-separated random list. 

in turn, that doesn't help much to my usage case. i just wanted to choose a video from the playlist, using the video id!

Comment: index does not seem to work anymore :/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Greg answer I make this code, and works!

```
`
<?php
$min=1;  $max=8;  //the number of videos on your playlist
?>
<object width="746" height="413"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/p/CAAA1242CA3E37B4?version=3&hl=es_ES&fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<?php
//in index the script randomize the numbre between $min $max
echo "
<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/p/CAAA1242CA3E7B4?version=3&hl=es_ES&fs=1&index=".rand($min,$max)."\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"746\" height=\"413\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\">
</embed>
";
?>
</object>
`
```

Answer (score 1):

In my context I slightly changed the coding by Mauricio:

```
 index=<?php print(rand(1,50)) ?>
```

(I put min and max in here directly)

Answer (score -1):

You shoud check http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ 
or http://popcornjs.org/ .

here is an example using PopCornJS:
http://www.seuratt.net/rhi-popcorn/demos/videojs-playlist.html