# Make embedded YouTube Playlist start at random index

Tags: javascript, php, html, youtube

I've been searching for a way to make my embedded playlist start with a random video.

This is what I tried:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLPmj00V6sF0s0k3Homcg1jkP0mLjddPgJ&index=<?php print(rand(1,11)) ?>?rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&authide=0&iv_load_policy=3&?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Sadly, this does not work for some reason. Neither did it with echo. Other solutions (as well few on stackoverflow https://shrty.top/j) did not work either. 
Any ideas?

Comment: is it a troll or why do i get the **Troll** Vid when i try ur Code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding Youtube playlist but starting from random video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831210/embedding-youtube-playlist-but-starting-from-random-video)

Comment: It is a playlist with funny videos. This is no troll. Try it with a different playlist, it won't work either. With this code it shows the same video all the time (Rickroll)

Comment: Nice timing, also encountering this today. Using the modern iFrame API (the only non-deprecated one) I'm not seeing a way to do this :(

Comment: Vincent P's answer here gets you 90% of the way, EXCEPT it starts on the first video and shuffles afterwards. Might be a good starting point? Let me know if you figure out how to shuffle on initial load!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035124/why-youtube-javascript-player-api-open-a-different-url-than-the-one-in-my-code

Comment: This issue has not been resolved so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. This works:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var videos = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ"];
        window.onload = function () {
            var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
            var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            var randomVideoUrl = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
            player.setAttribute('width', '640');
            player.setAttribute('height', '390');
            player.setAttribute('src', randomVideoUrl);
            playerDiv.appendChild(player);
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="random_player" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.