# How to play a YouTube playlist randomly when you access or refresh a page

Tags: iframe, indexing, youtube

I'm creating a source code to use as a widget on my blog.

This is what I tried.

```
<iframe width="170" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLLpwaElWBRDduC5vAw7EDy4bQSn7eevqE&index=".rand($min,$max)."&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Unfortunately, index code did not run on this source code. I'd like to ask for help if you know how to play the YouTube playlist randomly using the index function.:(

Comment: can you give some more details?

Comment: The original source code did not include index. In fact, other functions except index have been properly applied. I don't know much about html, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998539/make-embedded-youtube-playlist-start-at-random-index ←I saw this place for reference.